# Could not cast TextBlock to Element - Android.gms.Vision

Tags: android, kotlin, vision

Code crashes at selected line. Reason: Cannot cast TextBlock to Element.
One would think that the SparseArray(items) is of type 'Element' because of previous declarations.(language: Kotlin)

[image]